# Detect black out line on an image ios

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a .PNG file.That image have a white background and only black out line .

I want to detect that black out line when user touch on the image. In this image how can i  detect flowers out line by touch

e.g.

[image]

How is this possible?

please help me...

Comment: what is wrong in my question ? why down vote?

Answer (score 2):

Create the category of `UIView` class. Add below function into it.

```
@implementation UIView (ColorOfPoint)

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
      unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
      CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
      CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapFloatComponents);
      CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);
      [self.layer renderInContext:context];
      CGContextRelease(context);
      CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
      UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

      return color;
}
@end
```

Use it by making below call:

```
  UIColor *col = [YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW colorOfPoint:CGPOINT_WHERE_USER_TOUCHED];
```

Comment: is this possible without category?

Comment: Yes.. Make it as your normal function and pass your UIImageView and CGPoint as arguments.

Comment: shows error Property 'layer' not found on object of type 'classname *'

Comment: use imageview.layer instead of self.layer as it is now moved from category to normal class function.

Comment: only alpha value get change ,sometimes it shows 0 sometimes it shows 1 ,not getting perfect RGB and alpha

Comment: Answer modified. See the last argument for CGBitmapContextCreate function.

Comment: i am using this link classes https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit and getting RGBA as i mention above.but when i tried this code in my class then it is not calling by this    UIColor *col = [YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW colorOfPoint:CGPOINT_WHERE_USER_TOUCHED];

Answer (score 1):

ok got solution only this class will help [UIView+ColorOfPoint](https://github.com/ivanzoid/ikit)